# 404 page not found (for image to display default)

Tags: html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

i have very serious problem if any tech expert can help...thank you in advance..

i have below html file **on which i dont have any control**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://cafebar.ro/home.php" target=_blank><img class="photo" width="100%"     src="http://cityadvertisement.com/Photo-Gadgets/Sportsgirls/photo-102.jpg"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

now what i want to do is if the above image does't found then it should display default image (i can not update above html file). but on server i can create e404.html page which will be displayed if image is not exist on server but when i run above html page it doesnt display anything... and On my yahoo hosting i dont have .htaccess

can anybody tell me how i can display default image on above html page.

Comment: no...on yahoo small business i can not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot change the HTML document, then you are out luck unless you can affect the server referred to in the `src` attribute, i.e. cityadvertisement.com. It is the response of that server that matters, not some error response of some other server to some other request.

If you have access to that server, you should make it return some default *image* in response to the request for http://cityadvertisement.com/Photo-Gadgets/Sportsgirls/photo-102.jpg when a real image does not exist. Returning an HTML (error) document does not help, because the browsers expect an image and will discard an HTML document response when processing an `img` tag.

I don’t quite understand why you say that you can “create e404.html page” but can’t use .htaccess. Does this mean that the server has fixed .htaccess that sets e404.html as error document for 404 errors? Then you’re stuck, I’m afraid.

Comment: hi thanks for reply... i have access to cityadvertisement.com.. and you are true browser is expecting the image. but now point is how to return default image to requester. ??

and e404.html page is when the requested image/or anything else does not found on server then it will redirect to e404.html page and whatever the contents are there it will display.

But in our case we have to return the image..and thats the point i am not able to do.

thank you in advance.

Comment: The point is that the server should not send back a 404 error code but a normal 200 OK response (or maybe 302 Found), serving a fallback image if the real image is not available. Whether and how this can be done depends on the server software, its settings, and your privileges there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be a optimal solution...
create a new page with iframe of the html page that you have. Have script to check if the image is available, else change the image src at runtime.